# Is this function a secure MAC?

Tags: hmac

Consider the following function:
$f_k(mm')=\operatorname{HMAC}_{\operatorname{HMAC}_k(m)}(mm')$

Can I use $f$ as a secure MAC?

Comment: Given that HMAC is a PRF, I'm reasonably sure that $f$ is also a PRF and therfore a secure MAC. Though I'm too tired to do the proof today.

Comment: This is roughly an instance of the cascade construction.  See https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/cascade.html and https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#xsalsa for analysis.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage the papers you have referred are very complex. Could you provide a simple proof? I think I can claim that if f is not PRF, then there is a distinguisher ${\cal D}$ that can distinguish a random number from $f$ with probability better than random guess and then I show that having such a distinguisher enables us to create a distinguisher for HMAC with the same probability which is not correct.

Comment: The short answer is that if the distinguishing advantage against your HMAC (under whatever hash function you've chosen) is at most $\varepsilon$, then the distinguishing advantage of any $q$-query adversary against your 2-level cascade composition is at most $\varepsilon + q\varepsilon$.  Maybe at some point I will be inclined to elaborate in a full answer but that point is not right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at $k' = \operatorname{HMAC}_k(m)$ as a key derivation function then you'd expect that $\operatorname{HMAC}_{k'}(mm')$ is secure, even if $m$ is also used to derive $k'$. So from a purely functional point of view then yes, this should be secure.

Also from a functional view I would wonder why there is a repetition of $m$, because as it is used to derive key $k'$ it is already included in the calculation of the MAC value, and repeating it is therefore moot; the repetition of $m$ doesn't do anything for security. You could just use $m$ for the KDF alone, so then the outer HMAC is just $\operatorname{HMAC}_{k'}(m')$

Finally, the presumption is of course that $k$ has enough bits to be used as a HMAC key; generally the same size key as the hash output is recommended.

---

I don't see any reason why $f_k(mm')=\operatorname{HMAC}_k(\operatorname{enc}(m,m'))$ would not work, where $\operatorname{enc}$ is a canonical encoding function. This is a more efficient MAC if $m$ is large.